# pip install cx_Oracle -> failed with exit status 1120

Tags: windows, python-3.x, visual-c++, pip

I'm trying to install cx_Oracle, but i've faced with the problem while installing.

I've got an error:

> LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _DllMainCRTStartup 
>   build\lib.win-amd64-3.4_mysql.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 56
>   unresolved extern als   error: command 'c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin \amd64\link.exe' failed
>   with exit status 1120

**System Info:**

Windows 7 x64

Python 3.4.3 x64.

I use the following guide for setup C++ part of installation:
http://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/12/21/compiling-python-extensions-on-windows/#id7

I've googled a lot of issues, but i didn't manage to find solution for my own one. Also I've got the same error while installing MySQL-python.

Answer (score 2):

1. you must install oracle client first
2. make sure :win7 x64; python x64; oracle client x64
3. pip install cx_Oracle

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue with the source install, but the binaries got it working for me. Install the binary from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cx_oracle. If you need here is the guide for the pip wheel install: https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#installing-from-wheels

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this commands in command line.

1. git clone https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle.git cx_Oracle
2. cd cx_Oracle
3. git submodule init
4. git submodule update
5. pip install cx_Oracle

here is a link also: [link to try]